# docker compose - What does external property signify under networks?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the below docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
networks:
  network1:
    name: my-net
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

---

What does `external` property signify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means `docker-compose` won't create the network. The network should be created externally before running `docker-compose up`. By default, compose manages the network creation. `external: True` flag is used to make the containers join a pre-existing network instead.

[*From docs:*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#network-configuration-reference)

> **external**
>
> If set to true, specifies that this network has been created
> outside of Compose. docker-compose up does not attempt to create it,
> and raises an error if it doesn’t exist.